# How to show a non_field_errors ValidationError raised in model.clean() in inline admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Using Django 2.2 I added a custom `clean()` method to a model.

```
class MyModel(Model):
    employees = models.ManyToManyField(Employee)

    def clean(self):
        raise ValidationError({'non_field_errors': _("Error message here.")})

        super().clean()
```

I am showing this model in the Django admin using an `InlineModelAdmin`, `TabularInline` to be precise, code looks like this:

```
class MyModelInline(BaseModelTabularInline):
    model = MyModel.employees.through
```

And in `EmployeeAdmin`:

```
@admin.register(Employee)
class EmployeeAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):

    inlines = (MyModelInline)
```

I've hidden some code, don't know if my employer would like me to share it. But when I now try to save an instance of `MyModel` using the `InlineModelAdmin`, I get an error `'MyModelForm' has no field named 'non_field_errors'.`

Can anyone tell me how to have this field available, so that I can display potential validation errors (coming from `MyModel.clean()`)

PS.

I notice that raising `ValidationErrors` for other fields (that are on my model) works perfecly, example:

```
raise ValidationError({'confidential_level': _("Error message.")})
```

Comment: Use `__all__` or better, `from django.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS` and use that (which by default is `"__all__"`)

Answer (score 2):

Use `__all__` or better, `from django.core.exceptions import NON_FIELD_ERRORS` and use that (which by default is `"__all__"`)

Comment: Thanks, I see it's `django.core.exceptions` by the way. Tried to change it, but it won't let me, since I need more characters changed.

Comment: oops indeed! my bad